# React native Stack Navigator version 5.x

Tags: react-native

**i have this stack navigator in version 4 **

```
const SearchStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Search: {
      screen: Search,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Rechercher'
      }
    },
    FilmDetail: {
      screen: FilmDetail
    }
  })
```

**but i wanted to write it in version 5 like this**

```
const Stack= createStackNavigator();
function MyStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Search" component={Search}  />
      <Stack.Screen name="Filmdetail" component={FilmDetail} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

*but i need one thing*, **the navigationOptions** ,*how to add it  plz*

Answer (score 0):

```js
function StackScreen() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{ title: 'My home' }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

This answer your question?